# How to add NSDebug.h and use NSZombie in iPhone SDK

Tags: iphone, cocoa, cocoa-touch, debugging

I want to enable NSZombies for my iPhone app.

I have read several articles online and I am still unsure of the exact procedure.

I know I have to set the Environment Variables, which I have done:

```
NSZombieEnabled = YES
NSDebugEnabled = YES
NSDeallocateZombies = NO
```

I think (I'm not sure), I have to import NSDebug.h.
When I check the headers of the Foundation Framework in my project, there is no NSDebug.h.

After some research, I found them in the iPhoneSimulator Foundation Framework.
So (and I'm not sure if this is correct), I imported the iPhoneSimualtor Foundation Framework into my project.
I noticed that the file STILL does not show up in the project window, even though I can locate it in the Finder.(Is this normal behavior?).

So I opened up main and added:

```
#ifdef TARGET_IPHONE_SIMULATOR
#import <Foundation/NSDebug.h>
#endif
```

I am not sure if that is right either.  After this I still can't get the NSZombie to work (unless I have misunderstood what it is supposed to do)
I am expecting to see a log of " NSZombie sent a release... " or something.  But I don't see anything

I'm sure I'm just not doing this right, a good step by step would be appreciated.
Thanks

Also of note, I have also enabled:

```
NSMallocStacklLogging = YES
MallocStackLoggingNoCompact = YES
```

Comment: typo on `NSMallocStackLogging` in last code block

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You don't have to include NSDebug.h or import any special frameworks to use NSZombies. Basically, turn 'em on in your environment variables, and then, if you attempt to message a dealloc'd object, THEN you'll see something in your console, along the lines of:

`2009-02-10 21:17:08.546 MyApp[16926:20b] *** -[CFString _cfTypeID]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x4babc0`

Comment: Thanks, I thought I was getting too involved in this. 
I set a breakpoint at -[NSZombie release].  It appears to get disabled as execution begins. Is that normal?   
Also, should my app still crash?  
I thought since the NSZombie object was still there, my program would continue executing.
Thanks

Comment: You should get a console message when ANY message is sent to an NSZombie; You should break automatically, no breakpoint required.

Answer (score 34):

Are you setting the environment variable correctly? The step by step guide is

1. Double-click an executable in the Executables group of your Xcode project.
2. Click the Arguments tab.
3. In the "Variables to be set in the environment:" section, make a variable called "NSZombieEnabled" and set its value to "YES".

You don't need to #import NSDebug.h

Comment: +1. I had the same issue as OP, and you helped me find it. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

-1 to Apple. Debug builds should be running with full instrumentation out of the box (with a choice to opt-out). Also see http://www.cocoadev.com/index.pl?NSZombieEnabled for additional itms of interest to someone who is developing and debugging a program.