# EXC_BAD_ACCESS in CALayerCollectLayers_ on the iPhone

Tags: iphone, crash

When running on the device:

```
Program received signal:  “EXC_BAD_ACCESS”.
```

Debugger:

```
#0  0x31e11158 in CALayerCollectLayers_
#1  0x31e11180 in CALayerCollectLayers_
#2  0x31e11180 in CALayerCollectLayers_
#3  0x31dd7428 in CALayerDisplayIfNeeded
#4  0x31dd5780 in CAContextCommitTransaction
#5  0x31dd543c in CATransactionCommit
#6  0x3026a0ec in __CFRunLoopDoObservers
#7  0x30269418 in CFRunLoopRunSpecific
#8  0x30269326 in CFRunLoopRunInMode
#9  0x306941fe in -[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) runMode:beforeDate:]
#10 0x30694f9a in -[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) run]
#11 0x0000319e in -[AppController createInStreamThread] at AppController.m:395
#12 0x30672e08 in -[NSThread main]
#13 0x30672cd6 in __NSThread__main__
#14 0x3146178c in _pthread_body
```

When running in the Simulator:

```
modifying layer that is being finalized - 0x52f2b0
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This type of defect can be difficult to track down. I'm glad you found it so quickly. Luckily there are some good tools to help you.

first of all, use [clang static language analysis](http://clang.llvm.org/StaticAnalysisUsage.html#BasicUsage) it can find this sort of defect without you ever running the code.

If you hit this defect after that, turn on [NSZombies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/535060/how-to-add-nsdebug-h-and-use-nszombie-in-iphone-sdk), MallocStackLogging and MallocStackLoggingNoCompact then use [malloc_history](http://developer.apple.com/DOCUMENTATION/DARWIN/Reference/ManPages/man1/malloc_history.1.html) to find where you allocation was performed. It's not perfect but it's a great help.

Answer (score 2):

It turns out that I was over-releasing a UIButton.

```
UIButton *button = [self buttonWith...];
...
[self addSubview:button];
[button release];
```

But [self buttonWith...] returned an autoreleased button, so my release shouldn't have been there. Removing that line fixed the crash.