# Getting “EXC_BAD_ACCESS”

Tags: objective-c

I have an Address interface as this:

```
    @interface AddressCard : NSObject 
{
    NSString *name;
    NSString *email;
}

@property (copy, nonatomic) NSString *name, *email;

-(void) print;
-(void) setName:(NSString *) theName andEmail:(NSString *) theEmail;
-(void) dealloc;
@end
```

And implementation as:

```
#import "AddressCard.h"

@implementation AddressCard

@synthesize name, email;

-(void) setName:(NSString *) theName andEmail: (NSString *) theEmail
{
    self.name = theName;
    self.email = theEmail;
}
-(void) print
{
    NSLog (@"==============================");
    NSLog(@"| %-21s |", [self.name UTF8String]);
    NSLog(@"| %-21s |", [self.email UTF8String]);
    NSLog (@"==============================");
}

-(void) dealloc
{
    [name release];
    [email release];
    [super dealloc];
}

@end
```

When I run it I keep getting an EXEC_BAD_ACCESS during the pool drain. I'm unable to find the cause and any help is appreciated. This is my first step into Objective-C so please bear with me.

thanks
Sunit

Comment: I don't see anything that would cause that error in the code you posted. I find the use of UTF8String rather than just printing the string itself suspicious, but that shouldn't have anything to do with any pool being drained. More likely the error is in where this class is used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the error occurs when draining the pool, I might be suspicious that you've already deallocated the object by that point, and the object is over-released (although generally you'll get a "malloc double free" error for this) or perhaps the memory has already been overwritten by something else. I'd suggest running it with zombies enabled, as in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/971249#979184) — if you have Snow Leopard you can use the Zombies tool in Instruments from Xcode's **Run** menu. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

That example looks quite familiar - I just worked through that book myself!  The code you've posted above is fine, so the problem must be elsewhere.  You might try checking out [the author's forum](http://classroomm.com/objective-c/index.php?board=47.0) - the source code for each of the steps for that chapter is posted there.

As others have suggested, you might want to look for extra 'release' calls.

Answer (score -1):

Since you are releasing the strings in your dealloc method it would appear that your AddressCard object assumes ownership of the strings but you use this line to define the properites:

```
@property (copy, nonatomic) NSString *name, *email;
```

Using copy means that your object is not retaining the strings. Try changing that line to this:

```
@property (retain, nonatomic) NSString *name, *email;
```

Using retain means that your object will retain the strings until you release them in your dealloc.

Hopefully that will solve the problem.

Comment: Incorrect. The `copy` attribute means that it calls the `-copy` message and assumes ownership of the copy. You're thinking of `assign`, which is used for primitives and delegates, etc.

Comment: Yes, my mistake, I was thinking of assign. Apologies.