# I am getting below message printed by xcode at the time of moving from one view to another view

Tags: iphone, objective-c

(633,0xac8ad2c0) malloc: *** error for object 0x6ab4b10: double free
*** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug

What does it mean? And How can I solve it?

Comment: this answer can help u.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/971249/how-to-find-the-cause-of-a-malloc-double-free-error

Comment: thanks @AppleVijay ! It would be helpful:)

Comment: thanks buddy. but before ask question pls search with that error in google. so u can find some useful information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of today! I solved this problem, the problem was there in my code, that's what I did to solved it, I used to Analyze my code from XCode IDE. Then I founded some memory leaks over there into my code! I used to remove it, and thats all! I solved it:)

Answer (score 1):

it means a free() has been done more than once on a allocated block.

do as the description says, set a break point and see what is causing the error i.e. add a symbol break point in xcode

run > breakpoints > add symbolic breakpoint  "malloc_error_break"

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/971249/how-to-find-the-cause-of-a-malloc-double-free-error