# Monodevelop: How to find the cause of a malloc “double free” error?

Tags: malloc, monodevelop

I´ve found this thread [How to find the cause of a malloc "double free" error?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/971249/how-to-find-the-cause-of-a-malloc-double-free-error) but that doesn´t give any useful information on how to debug this error in the mono environment:

So does anyone know how to debug such an error in Monodevelop?

```
MyApp(2121,0xb0185000) malloc: *** error for object 0x1068310: double free
*** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug
```

In the linked thread they´ve mentioned to set symbolic breakpoints but I´m not able to find the same function in monodevelop..

Thank you very much for your help!

Henning

Comment: What is your app written in? MonoTouch?

Comment: Yes. I got a very kind response from Xamarin: Hi,

This message is from iOS and is assuming the one who reads it is using Xcode. This is not your case since you're using MonoTouch. MonoDevelop is not able to debug native code and it's not possible to put a breakpoint on malloc_error_break using MonoDevelop.

The easiest way to debug this is to put a breakpoint on the closest managed code you can, and then just single-step until you find the line of code that's causing this message.

I hope this helps,