# Same location 2 buttons in swift?

Tags: ios, swift, button, layout, position

I have 2 buttons in playerviewcontroller (record and stop at same location). I made stop button hidden from panel. I wanna make record button tapped action then hidden record button and show stop button. But its give me error.

malloc: *** error for object 0x14e1c010: pointer being freed was not allocated
*** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug

Comment: You may find your answer in this [link]
 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12049058/malloc-error-for-object-0x165060-pointer-being-freed-was-not-allocated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> You better use the same button for two purpose. Create a flag which stores the state. I.e. playing or paused. And do task according to the flag.
>   Then you wouldn't need to hide/show buttons.