# How to "set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug"

Tags: iphone, ios

I'm getting lots of console outputs like this without my application crashing:

> malloc: *** error for object 0xc6a3970: pointer being freed was not
>   allocated    *** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug

How can I find out which object or variable is affected?

I tried setting a symbolic breakpoint like this but it never halts:

[image]

Comment: I solve this issue by disable safari inspect. http://stackoverflow.com/a/43885754/6521116

Comment: One of the causes of this is a function/method which is supposed to return an object and it reaches the end of the function and does not return anything.

Answer (score 157, accepted):

Set a breakpoint on malloc_error_break() by opening the Breakpoint Navigator (View->Navigators->Show Breakpoint Navigator or ⌘8), clicking the plus button in the lower left corner, and selecting "Add Symbolic Breakpoint". In the popup that comes up, enter `malloc_error_break` in the Symbol field, then click Done.

EDIT: openfrog added a screenshot and indicated that he's already tried these steps without success *after* I posted my answer. With that edit, I'm not sure what to say. I haven't seen that fail to work myself, and indeed I always keep a breakpoint on malloc_error_break set.

Comment: This worked for me (without the module).  The cause of the issue for me was that I had a `UIImage` backed by a file, and I was overwriting the file with a different image.  This caused an error when I called `UIImagePNGRepresentation` on the original image (not when the file was actually overwritten).

Comment: I'm not getting a plus button in the lower-left corner of the `⌘7` bar...Perhaps you meant `⌘8`?

Comment: @ScottyBlades guessing the shortcut has changed. I wrote this answer 8 years and 7 major Xcode versions ago...

Comment: @AndrewMadsen  No worries, just checking if it makes sense to edit.

Comment: As of Xcode 12.4, you can get to it this way: Debug -> Breakpoints -> Create Synbolic Breakpoint (⌥ ⌘ \\)

Answer (score 49):

In your screenshot, you didn't specify any module: try setting "libsystem_c.dylib"

[image]

I did that, and it works : breakpoint stops here
(although the stacktrace often rise from some obscure system lib...)

Comment: Looks like the module name is different in iOS, it's: `libsystem_malloc.dylib`. Breakpoint works for me without specifying a module.

Answer (score 8):

I had the same problem with Xcode. I followed steps you gave and it didn't work.
I became crazy because in every forum I saw, all clues for this problem are the one you gave.
I finally saw I put a space after the malloc_error_break, I suppressed it and now it works.
A dumb problem but if the solution doesn't work, be sure you haven't put any space before and after the malloc_error_break.

Hope this message will help..

Comment: The space worked for me. I felt weird.

Answer (score 4):

I had given permissions I shouldn't have to write in some folders (especially /usr/bin/), and that caused the problem. I fixed it by opening Disk Utility and running 'Repair Disk Permissions' on the Macintosh HD disk.

Comment: Thanks, this fixed my borked machine.

Answer (score 2):

I solve it by close safari inspector. Refer to my **[post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43885754/6521116)**. I also found sound sometimes when I run my app for testing, then I open safari with auto inspector on, after this, I  do some action in my app then this issue triggered.

[image]