# ios remote camera image processing crashes

Tags: ios, multithreading, image-processing, sony, sony-camera-api

I have connected a remote camera using Sony CameraRemoteAPI SDK. Camera is connected successfully and I am getting the frames. The following code gets the incoming UIImage and assign to a UIImageView

`- (void) liveviewPaint:(UIImage*)image
{
    @synchronized(self)
    {
        [self.liveviewImageView setImage:image];
        image = NULL;
    }
}`

Then I needed to add face recognition to this UIImage. But when I try to do it the application runs out of memory and crashes. How can I effectively do face recognition with this remote camera feed? This is my current code

`- (void) liveviewPaint:(UIImage*)image
{
    @synchronized(self)
    {
        [self performSelectorInBackground:@selector(getFaceDetectedImage:) withObject:image];
        if ([[RecognitionAPI getSharedInstance] detectedImage]) {
            [self.liveviewImageView setImage:[[RecognitionAPI getSharedInstance] detectedImage]];
        } else {
            [self.liveviewImageView setImage:image];
        }
        image = NULL;
    }
}`

Here using a separate thread I am calling the face recognition function (getFaceDetectedImage). Once the face is recognized it is set as a instance variable in RecognitionAPI class(detectedImage). If the face is detected I set it to the image of the UIImageView(liveviewImageView) as follows
`[self.liveviewImageView setImage:[[RecognitionAPI getSharedInstance] detectedImage]];`

This is the output of the allocation tool without the face detection. App is not crashing this time.
[image]

This is the output of the allocation tool with the face detection. App is **crashing** this time.
[image]

I am using apple inbuilt CIDetector for face recognition. I tried with opencv, but at that time also the app is crashing.

This is error I am getting in the console

`Recognition(483,0x6a51000) malloc: *** mach_vm_map(size=2691072) failed (error code=3)
*** error: can't allocate region
*** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug
Recognition(483,0x6a51000) malloc: *** mach_vm_map(size=675840) failed (error code=3)
*** error: can't allocate region
*** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug
Recognition(483,0x6a51000) malloc: *** mach_vm_map(size=2691072) failed (error code=3)
*** error: can't allocate region
*** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug
Recognition(483,0x6a51000) malloc: *** mach_vm_map(size=675840) failed (error code=3)
*** error: can't allocate region
*** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug
Recognition(483,0x6a51000) malloc: *** mach_vm_map(size=2691072) failed (error code=3)
*** error: can't allocate region
*** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug
Recognition(483,0x6a51000) malloc: ***`

Also I am getting total 59 threads that fail to finish. This is a screenshot of it.
[image]

I want to know how to evade this crash and how to do the image processing efficiently. I think I will need a good design for this. Can anyone help?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14045208/how-to-set-a-breakpoint-in-malloc-error-break-to-debug . This might help u to narrow down on the problem (somewhat).

Comment: I tried.No debug points were hit