# pointer being freed was not allocated *** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug

Tags: ios, xcode

My application got this error:

> MyAppication(59098,0x11323a380) malloc: *** error for object
>   0x7fbfcb298670: pointer being freed was not allocated
>   *** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug

When I run it in simulator. But it's working fine in device.

I found an answer online:

[How to “set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14045208/how-to-set-a-breakpoint-in-malloc-error-break-to-debug)

I set the break point, but it didn't help because it only shows the break point on some assembly code. Anybody has experience on how to debug this kind of issue? Please advise. Thanks.

[image: Set break point]

[image: Break]