# error for object 0x7faa4d081f98: pointer being freed was not allocated Ruby (ROR) malloc_error_break

Tags: ruby-on-rails, c, ruby, debugging, malloc

We have a malloc_error_break on our Ruby (ROR) API. We have tried on different devices. (OSX).

This is my error:

```
(68785,0x700004011000) malloc: *** error for object 0x7faa4d081f98: pointer being freed was not allocated
*** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug
```

When I try to debug trough **lldb** i got this:

```
* thread #30: tid = 0x4a0457, 0x00007fff54ab2962 libsystem_malloc.dylib`malloc_error_break, name = 'thread_pool.rb*', stop reason = breakpoint 1.1
  * frame #0: 0x00007fff54ab2962 libsystem_malloc.dylib`malloc_error_break
    frame #1: 0x00007fff54aa47a9 libsystem_malloc.dylib`free + 400
    frame #2: 0x0000000103acf902 libruby.2.3.0.dylib`objspace_xfree(objspace=0x00007faa48e09fd0, ptr=0x00007faa4d081f98, old_size=0) + 50 at gc.c:7720
    frame #3: 0x0000000103acf8c9 libruby.2.3.0.dylib`ruby_sized_xfree(x=0x00007faa4d081f98, size=0) + 57 at gc.c:7809
    frame #4: 0x0000000103ac7739 libruby.2.3.0.dylib`ruby_xfree(x=0x00007faa4d081f98) + 25 at gc.c:7816
    frame #5: 0x0000000103c5efc5 libruby.2.3.0.dylib`rb_iseq_free(iseq=0x00007faa544561a8) + 245 at iseq.c:82
    frame #6: 0x0000000103ad5b03 libruby.2.3.0.dylib`obj_free(objspace=0x00007faa48e09fd0, obj=140369535001000) + 1955 at gc.c:2238
    frame #7: 0x0000000103ad4e77 libruby.2.3.0.dylib`gc_page_sweep(objspace=0x00007faa48e09fd0, heap=0x00007faa48e09ff0, sweep_page=0x00007faa53537980) + 487 at gc.c:3396
    frame #8: 0x0000000103ad4aab libruby.2.3.0.dylib`gc_sweep_step(objspace=0x00007faa48e09fd0, heap=0x00007faa48e09ff0) + 139 at gc.c:3575
    frame #9: 0x0000000103ad445c libruby.2.3.0.dylib`gc_sweep_continue(objspace=0x00007faa48e09fd0, heap=0x00007faa48e09ff0) + 92 at gc.c:3640
    frame #10: 0x0000000103ad436c libruby.2.3.0.dylib`heap_prepare(objspace=0x00007faa48e09fd0, heap=0x00007faa48e09ff0) + 44 at gc.c:1638
    frame #11: 0x0000000103ad42dc libruby.2.3.0.dylib`heap_get_freeobj_from_next_freepage(objspace=0x00007faa48e09fd0, heap=0x00007faa48e09ff0) + 44 at gc.c:1661
    frame #12: 0x0000000103ad420f libruby.2.3.0.dylib`heap_get_freeobj(objspace=0x00007faa48e09fd0, heap=0x00007faa48e09ff0) + 95 at gc.c:1695
    frame #13: 0x0000000103ad4121 libruby.2.3.0.dylib`newobj_slowpath(klass=140369362911320, flags=5, v1=0, v2=0, v3=0, objspace=0x00007faa48e09fd0, wb_protected=1) + 305 at gc.c:1824
    frame #14: 0x0000000103ad3f8c libruby.2.3.0.dylib`newobj_slowpath_wb_protected(klass=140369362911320, flags=5, v1=0, v2=0, v3=0, objspace=0x00007faa48e09fd0) + 76 at gc.c:1836
    frame #15: 0x0000000103ac79ae libruby.2.3.0.dylib`newobj_of(klass=140369362911320, flags=5, v1=0, v2=0, v3=0, wb_protected=1) + 270 at gc.c:1868
    frame #16: 0x0000000103ac7a22 libruby.2.3.0.dylib`rb_wb_protected_newobj_of(klass=140369362911320, flags=5) + 50 at gc.c:1884
    frame #17: 0x0000000103be810c libruby.2.3.0.dylib`str_alloc(klass=140369362911320) + 28 at string.c:635
    frame #18: 0x0000000103be5eab libruby.2.3.0.dylib`str_new0(klass=140369362911320, ptr="9102ebff-2d7b-4e39-8173-d986c3ba9be0", len=36, termlen=1) + 187 at string.c:657
    frame #19: 0x0000000103be5cba libruby.2.3.0.dylib`str_new(klass=140369362911320, ptr="9102ebff-2d7b-4e39-8173-d986c3ba9be0", len=36) + 42 at string.c:677
    frame #20: 0x0000000103be5c84 libruby.2.3.0.dylib`rb_str_new(ptr="9102ebff-2d7b-4e39-8173-d986c3ba9be0", len=36) + 36 at string.c:683
    frame #21: 0x0000000103be65ed libruby.2.3.0.dylib`rb_tainted_str_new(ptr="9102ebff-2d7b-4e39-8173-d986c3ba9be0", len=36) + 29 at string.c:800
    frame #22: 0x0000000104639eab pg_ext.bundle`pg_text_dec_string(conv=0x0000000000000000, val="9102ebff-2d7b-4e39-8173-d986c3ba9be0", len=36, tuple=410, field=11, enc_idx=1) + 43 at pg_text_decoder.c:68
    frame #23: 0x000000010463d58b pg_ext.bundle`pg_tmas_result_value(p_typemap=0x00007faa4ed83b30, result=140369525907680, tuple=410, field=11) + 267 at pg_type_map_all_strings.c:36
    frame #24: 0x000000010463e300 pg_ext.bundle`pg_tmbc_result_value(p_typemap=0x00007faa553ec820, result=140369525907680, tuple=410, field=11) + 624 at pg_type_map_by_column.c:111
    frame #25: 0x0000000104639306 pg_ext.bundle`pgresult_values(self=140369525907680) + 198 at pg_result.c:905
    frame #26: 0x0000000103c88233 libruby.2.3.0.dylib`call_cfunc_0(func=(pg_ext.bundle`pgresult_values at pg_result.c:892), recv=140369525907680, argc=0, argv=0x00000001062a78c0) + 35 at vm_insnhelper.c:1469
    frame #27: 0x0000000103c86b91 libruby.2.3.0.dylib`vm_call_cfunc_with_frame(th=0x00007faa535450f0, reg_cfp=0x00000001063a3fc0, calling=0x0000700003ff9810, ci=0x00007faa5247d1c0, cc=0x00007faa5247fa10) + 593 at vm_insnhelper.c:1642
    frame #28: 0x0000000103c82a8a libruby.2.3.0.dylib`vm_call_cfunc(th=0x00007faa535450f0, reg_cfp=0x00000001063a3fc0, calling=0x0000700003ff9810, ci=0x00007faa5247d1c0, cc=0x00007faa5247fa10) + 170 at vm_insnhelper.c:1737
    frame #29: 0x0000000103c6c850 libruby.2.3.0.dylib`vm_exec_core(th=0x00007faa535450f0, initial=0) + 12688 at insns.def:994
    frame #30: 0x0000000103c7d6c7 libruby.2.3.0.dylib`vm_exec(th=0x00007faa535450f0) + 183 at vm.c:1693
    frame #31: 0x0000000103c8dadf libruby.2.3.0.dylib`vm_call0_body(th=0x00007faa535450f0, calling=0x0000700003ffa188, ci=0x0000700003ffa170, cc=0x0000700003ffa148, argv=0x00000001062a7588) + 415 at vm_eval.c:182
    frame #32: 0x0000000103c76d69 libruby.2.3.0.dylib`vm_call0(th=0x00007faa535450f0, recv=140369479578840, id=6113, argc=0, argv=0x00000001062a7588, me=0x00007faa5432f860) + 121 at vm_eval.c:61
    frame #33: 0x0000000103c76cdb libruby.2.3.0.dylib`rb_vm_call(th=0x00007faa535450f0, recv=140369479578840, id=6113, argc=0, argv=0x00000001062a7588, me=0x00007faa5432f860) + 59 at vm_eval.c:267
    frame #34: 0x0000000103ab4fb4 libruby.2.3.0.dylib`rb_method_call_with_block(argc=0, argv=0x00000001062a7588, method=140369533794440, pass_procval=8) + 548 at proc.c:1998
    frame #35: 0x0000000103ab4d7b libruby.2.3.0.dylib`rb_method_call(argc=0, argv=0x00000001062a7588, method=140369533794440) + 91 at proc.c:1963
    frame #36: 0x0000000103c8820a libruby.2.3.0.dylib`call_cfunc_m1(func=(libruby.2.3.0.dylib`rb_method_call at proc.c:1961), recv=140369533794440, argc=0, argv=0x00000001062a7588) + 42 at vm_insnhelper.c:1463
    frame #37: 0x0000000103c86b91 libruby.2.3.0.dylib`vm_call_cfunc_with_frame(th=0x00007faa535450f0, reg_cfp=0x00000001063a43c0, calling=0x0000700003ffb0f0, ci=0x00007faa4ea400a0, cc=0x00007faa4f4068c0) + 593 at vm_insnhelper.c:1642
    frame #38: 0x0000000103c82a8a libruby.2.3.0.dylib`vm_call_cfunc(th=0x00007faa535450f0, reg_cfp=0x00000001063a43c0, calling=0x0000700003ffb0f0, ci=0x00007faa4ea400a0, cc=0x00007faa4f4068c0) + 170 at vm_insnhelper.c:1737
    frame #39: 0x0000000103c6c850 libruby.2.3.0.dylib`vm_exec_core(th=0x00007faa535450f0, initial=0) + 12688 at insns.def:994
    frame #40: 0x0000000103c7d6c7 libruby.2.3.0.dylib`vm_exec(th=0x00007faa535450f0) + 183 at vm.c:1693
    frame #41: 0x0000000103c8f5f2 libruby.2.3.0.dylib`invoke_bmethod(th=0x00007faa535450f0, iseq=0x00007faa4b3de3c8, self=140369479578840, block=0x00007faa54c33d20, me=0x00007faa4c0a6c18, type=161, opt_pc=0) + 482 at vm.c:942
    frame #42: 0x0000000103c8f288 libruby.2.3.0.dylib`invoke_block_from_c_0(th=0x00007faa535450f0, block=0x00007faa54c33d20, self=140369479578840, argc=0, argv=0x0000700003ffbc20, blockptr=0x0000000000000000, cref=0x0000000000000000, splattable=0) + 1192 at vm.c:976
    frame #43: 0x0000000103c9121a libruby.2.3.0.dylib`invoke_block_from_c_unsplattable(th=0x00007faa535450f0, block=0x00007faa54c33d20, self=140369479578840, argc=0, argv=0x0000700003ffbc20, blockptr=0x0000000000000000, cref=0x0000000000000000) + 90 at vm.c:998
    frame #44: 0x0000000103c7c5dc libruby.2.3.0.dylib`vm_invoke_bmethod(th=0x00007faa535450f0, proc=0x00007faa54c33d20, self=140369479578840, argc=0, argv=0x0000700003ffbc20, blockptr=0x0000000000000000) + 76 at vm.c:1062
    frame #45: 0x0000000103c876fb libruby.2.3.0.dylib`vm_call_bmethod_body(th=0x00007faa535450f0, calling=0x0000700003ffcc60, ci=0x0000700003ffbe58, cc=0x0000700003ffbe30, argv=0x0000700003ffbc20) + 107 at vm_insnhelper.c:1766
    frame #46: 0x0000000103c82f41 libruby.2.3.0.dylib`vm_call_bmethod(th=0x00007faa535450f0, cfp=0x00000001063a4400, calling=0x0000700003ffcc60, ci=0x0000700003ffbe58, cc=0x0000700003ffbe30) + 321 at vm_insnhelper.c:1784
    frame #47: 0x0000000103c821d9 libruby.2.3.0.dylib`vm_call_method_each_type(th=0x00007faa535450f0, cfp=0x00000001063a4400, calling=0x0000700003ffcc60, ci=0x0000700003ffbe58, cc=0x0000700003ffbe30) + 825 at vm_insnhelper.c:2049
    frame #48: 0x0000000103c81cf0 libruby.2.3.0.dylib`vm_call_method(th=0x00007faa535450f0, cfp=0x00000001063a4400, calling=0x0000700003ffcc60, ci=0x0000700003ffbe58, cc=0x0000700003ffbe30) + 160 at vm_insnhelper.c:2151
    frame #49: 0x0000000103c83426 libruby.2.3.0.dylib`vm_call_opt_send(th=0x00007faa535450f0, reg_cfp=0x00000001063a4400, calling=0x0000700003ffcc60, orig_ci=0x00007faa5212d820, orig_cc=0x00007faa5212deb0) + 934 at vm_insnhelper.c:1850
    frame #50: 0x0000000103c8227c libruby.2.3.0.dylib`vm_call_method_each_type(th=0x00007faa535450f0, cfp=0x00000001063a4400, calling=0x0000700003ffcc60, ci=0x00007faa5212d820, cc=0x00007faa5212deb0) + 988 at vm_insnhelper.c:2060
    frame #51: 0x0000000103c82210 libruby.2.3.0.dylib`vm_call_method_each_type(th=0x00007faa535450f0, cfp=0x00000001063a4400, calling=0x0000700003ffcc60, ci=0x00007faa5212d820, cc=0x00007faa5212deb0) + 880 at vm_insnhelper.c:2054
    frame #52: 0x0000000103c81cf0 libruby.2.3.0.dylib`vm_call_method(th=0x00007faa535450f0, cfp=0x00000001063a4400, calling=0x0000700003ffcc60, ci=0x00007faa5212d820, cc=0x00007faa5212deb0) + 160 at vm_insnhelper.c:2151
    frame #53: 0x0000000103c83728 libruby.2.3.0.dylib`vm_call_super_method(th=0x00007faa535450f0, reg_cfp=0x00000001063a4400, calling=0x0000700003ffcc60, ci=0x00007faa5212d820, cc=0x00007faa5212deb0) + 88 at vm_insnhelper.c:2202
    frame #54: 0x0000000103c6c9aa libruby.2.3.0.dylib`vm_exec_core(th=0x00007faa535450f0, initial=0) + 13034 at insns.def:1014
    frame #55: 0x0000000103c7d6c7 libruby.2.3.0.dylib`vm_exec(th=0x00007faa535450f0) + 183 at vm.c:1693
    frame #56: 0x0000000103c8f3fa libruby.2.3.0.dylib`invoke_block(th=0x00007faa535450f0, iseq=0x00007faa4fc35068, self=140369479578840, block=0x00007faa4f2bc420, cref=0x0000000000000000, type=33, opt_pc=0) + 202 at vm.c:921
    frame #57: 0x0000000103c8f25c libruby.2.3.0.dylib`invoke_block_from_c_0(th=0x00007faa535450f0, block=0x00007faa4f2bc420, self=140369479578840, argc=0, argv=0x0000700003ffd810, blockptr=0x0000000000000000, cref=0x0000000000000000, splattable=0) + 1148 at vm.c:973
    frame #58: 0x0000000103c9121a libruby.2.3.0.dylib`invoke_block_from_c_unsplattable(th=0x00007faa535450f0, block=0x00007faa4f2bc420, self=140369479578840, argc=0, argv=0x0000700003ffd810, blockptr=0x0000000000000000, cref=0x0000000000000000) + 90 at vm.c:998
    frame #59: 0x0000000103c7c6e4 libruby.2.3.0.dylib`vm_invoke_proc(th=0x00007faa535450f0, proc=0x00007faa4f2bc420, self=140369479578840, argc=0, argv=0x0000700003ffd810, blockptr=0x0000000000000000) + 244 at vm.c:1046
    frame #60: 0x0000000103c7c575 libruby.2.3.0.dylib`rb_vm_invoke_proc(th=0x00007faa535450f0, proc=0x00007faa4f2bc420, argc=0, argv=0x0000700003ffd810, blockptr=0x0000000000000000) + 117 at vm.c:1074
    frame #61: 0x0000000103c83589 libruby.2.3.0.dylib`vm_call_opt_call(th=0x00007faa535450f0, cfp=0x00000001063a4500, calling=0x0000700003ffe430, ci=0x00007faa4dd57800, cc=0x00007faa4dd58a00) + 345 at vm_insnhelper.c:1868
    frame #62: 0x0000000103c6c850 libruby.2.3.0.dylib`vm_exec_core(th=0x00007faa535450f0, initial=0) + 12688 at insns.def:994
    frame #63: 0x0000000103c7d6c7 libruby.2.3.0.dylib`vm_exec(th=0x00007faa535450f0) + 183 at vm.c:1693
    frame #64: 0x0000000103c8f3fa libruby.2.3.0.dylib`invoke_block(th=0x00007faa535450f0, iseq=0x00007faa4ba77428, self=140369396978760, block=0x00007faa54a4aa50, cref=0x0000000000000000, type=33, opt_pc=0) + 202 at vm.c:921
    frame #65: 0x0000000103c8f25c libruby.2.3.0.dylib`invoke_block_from_c_0(th=0x00007faa535450f0, block=0x00007faa54a4aa50, self=140369396978760, argc=1, argv=0x0000700003ffefa0, blockptr=0x0000000000000000, cref=0x0000000000000000, splattable=0) + 1148 at vm.c:973
    frame #66: 0x0000000103c9121a libruby.2.3.0.dylib`invoke_block_from_c_unsplattable(th=0x00007faa535450f0, block=0x00007faa54a4aa50, self=140369396978760, argc=1, argv=0x0000700003ffefa0, blockptr=0x0000000000000000, cref=0x0000000000000000) + 90 at vm.c:998
    frame #67: 0x0000000103c7c6e4 libruby.2.3.0.dylib`vm_invoke_proc(th=0x00007faa535450f0, proc=0x00007faa54a4aa50, self=140369396978760, argc=1, argv=0x0000700003ffefa0, blockptr=0x0000000000000000) + 244 at vm.c:1046
    frame #68: 0x0000000103c7c575 libruby.2.3.0.dylib`rb_vm_invoke_proc(th=0x00007faa535450f0, proc=0x00007faa54a4aa50, argc=1, argv=0x0000700003ffefa0, blockptr=0x0000000000000000) + 117 at vm.c:1074
    frame #69: 0x0000000103c83589 libruby.2.3.0.dylib`vm_call_opt_call(th=0x00007faa535450f0, cfp=0x00000001063a4580, calling=0x0000700003fffbd0, ci=0x00007faa4dd61480, cc=0x00007faa4dd67f28) + 345 at vm_insnhelper.c:1868
    frame #70: 0x0000000103c6c850 libruby.2.3.0.dylib`vm_exec_core(th=0x00007faa535450f0, initial=0) + 12688 at insns.def:994
    frame #71: 0x0000000103c7d6c7 libruby.2.3.0.dylib`vm_exec(th=0x00007faa535450f0) + 183 at vm.c:1693
    frame #72: 0x0000000103c8f3fa libruby.2.3.0.dylib`invoke_block(th=0x00007faa535450f0, iseq=0x00007faa4ba0d9d8, self=140369556552120, block=0x00007faa54ca5d30, cref=0x0000000000000000, type=33, opt_pc=0) + 202 at vm.c:921
    frame #73: 0x0000000103c8f25c libruby.2.3.0.dylib`invoke_block_from_c_0(th=0x00007faa535450f0, block=0x00007faa54ca5d30, self=140369556552120, argc=0, argv=0x0000700004000740, blockptr=0x0000000000000000, cref=0x0000000000000000, splattable=0) + 1148 at vm.c:973
    frame #74: 0x0000000103c9121a libruby.2.3.0.dylib`invoke_block_from_c_unsplattable(th=0x00007faa535450f0, block=0x00007faa54ca5d30, self=140369556552120, argc=0, argv=0x0000700004000740, blockptr=0x0000000000000000, cref=0x0000000000000000) + 90 at vm.c:998
    frame #75: 0x0000000103c7c6e4 libruby.2.3.0.dylib`vm_invoke_proc(th=0x00007faa535450f0, proc=0x00007faa54ca5d30, self=140369556552120, argc=0, argv=0x0000700004000740, blockptr=0x0000000000000000) + 244 at vm.c:1046
    frame #76: 0x0000000103c7c575 libruby.2.3.0.dylib`rb_vm_invoke_proc(th=0x00007faa535450f0, proc=0x00007faa54ca5d30, argc=0, argv=0x0000700004000740, blockptr=0x0000000000000000) + 117 at vm.c:1074
    frame #77: 0x0000000103c83589 libruby.2.3.0.dylib`vm_call_opt_call(th=0x00007faa535450f0, cfp=0x00000001063a4600, calling=0x0000700004001360, ci=0x00007faa4aef6f40, cc=0x00007faa4dd60e40) + 345 at vm_insnhelper.c:1868
    frame #78: 0x0000000103c6c850 libruby.2.3.0.dylib`vm_exec_core(th=0x00007faa535450f0, initial=0) + 12688 at insns.def:994
    frame #79: 0x0000000103c7d6c7 libruby.2.3.0.dylib`vm_exec(th=0x00007faa535450f0) + 183 at vm.c:1693
    frame #80: 0x0000000103c8f3fa libruby.2.3.0.dylib`invoke_block(th=0x00007faa535450f0, iseq=0x00007faa4ba6cb90, self=140369494572960, block=0x00007faa54a4c050, cref=0x0000000000000000, type=161, opt_pc=0) + 202 at vm.c:921
    frame #81: 0x0000000103c8f25c libruby.2.3.0.dylib`invoke_block_from_c_0(th=0x00007faa535450f0, block=0x00007faa54a4c050, self=140369494572960, argc=2, argv=0x0000700004001ed0, blockptr=0x00000001063a47e0, cref=0x0000000000000000, splattable=0) + 1148 at vm.c:973
    frame #82: 0x0000000103c9121a libruby.2.3.0.dylib`invoke_block_from_c_unsplattable(th=0x00007faa535450f0, block=0x00007faa54a4c050, self=140369494572960, argc=2, argv=0x0000700004001ed0, blockptr=0x00000001063a47e0, cref=0x0000000000000000) + 90 at vm.c:998
    frame #83: 0x0000000103c7c6e4 libruby.2.3.0.dylib`vm_invoke_proc(th=0x00007faa535450f0, proc=0x00007faa54a4c050, self=140369494572960, argc=2, argv=0x0000700004001ed0, blockptr=0x00000001063a47e0) + 244 at vm.c:1046
    frame #84: 0x0000000103c7c575 libruby.2.3.0.dylib`rb_vm_invoke_proc(th=0x00007faa535450f0, proc=0x00007faa54a4c050, argc=2, argv=0x0000700004001ed0, blockptr=0x00000001063a47e0) + 117 at vm.c:1074
    frame #85: 0x0000000103c83589 libruby.2.3.0.dylib`vm_call_opt_call(th=0x00007faa535450f0, cfp=0x00000001063a47c0, calling=0x0000700004002b48, ci=0x00007faa4dd610a0, cc=0x00007faa4dd61150) + 345 at vm_insnhelper.c:1868
    frame #86: 0x0000000103c6c659 libruby.2.3.0.dylib`vm_exec_core(th=0x00007faa535450f0, initial=0) + 12185 at insns.def:963
    frame #87: 0x0000000103c7d6c7 libruby.2.3.0.dylib`vm_exec(th=0x00007faa535450f0) + 183 at vm.c:1693
    frame #88: 0x0000000103c8f3fa libruby.2.3.0.dylib`invoke_block(th=0x00007faa535450f0, iseq=0x00007faa4ba6d978, self=140369380986760, block=0x00007faa53020460, cref=0x0000000000000000, type=33, opt_pc=0) + 202 at vm.c:921
    frame #89: 0x0000000103c8f25c libruby.2.3.0.dylib`invoke_block_from_c_0(th=0x00007faa535450f0, block=0x00007faa53020460, self=140369380986760, argc=1, argv=0x0000700004003670, blockptr=0x00000001063a4820, cref=0x0000000000000000, splattable=0) + 1148 at vm.c:973
    frame #90: 0x0000000103c9121a libruby.2.3.0.dylib`invoke_block_from_c_unsplattable(th=0x00007faa535450f0, block=0x00007faa53020460, self=140369380986760, argc=1, argv=0x0000700004003670, blockptr=0x00000001063a4820, cref=0x0000000000000000) + 90 at vm.c:998
    frame #91: 0x0000000103c7c6e4 libruby.2.3.0.dylib`vm_invoke_proc(th=0x00007faa535450f0, proc=0x00007faa53020460, self=140369380986760, argc=1, argv=0x0000700004003670, blockptr=0x00000001063a4820) + 244 at vm.c:1046
    frame #92: 0x0000000103c7c575 libruby.2.3.0.dylib`rb_vm_invoke_proc(th=0x00007faa535450f0, proc=0x00007faa53020460, argc=1, argv=0x0000700004003670, blockptr=0x00000001063a4820) + 117 at vm.c:1074
    frame #93: 0x0000000103c83589 libruby.2.3.0.dylib`vm_call_opt_call(th=0x00007faa535450f0, cfp=0x00000001063a4800, calling=0x00007000040042e8, ci=0x00007faa4dd64a20, cc=0x00007faa4dd66900) + 345 at vm_insnhelper.c:1868
    frame #94: 0x0000000103c6c659 libruby.2.3.0.dylib`vm_exec_core(th=0x00007faa535450f0, initial=0) + 12185 at insns.def:963
    frame #95: 0x0000000103c7d6c7 libruby.2.3.0.dylib`vm_exec(th=0x00007faa535450f0) + 183 at vm.c:1693
    frame #96: 0x0000000103c8f3fa libruby.2.3.0.dylib`invoke_block(th=0x00007faa535450f0, iseq=0x00007faa4ba0dd70, self=140369556552120, block=0x00007faa54eafd80, cref=0x0000000000000000, type=33, opt_pc=0) + 202 at vm.c:921
    frame #97: 0x0000000103c8f25c libruby.2.3.0.dylib`invoke_block_from_c_0(th=0x00007faa535450f0, block=0x00007faa54eafd80, self=140369556552120, argc=1, argv=0x0000700004004e10, blockptr=0x0000000000000000, cref=0x0000000000000000, splattable=0) + 1148 at vm.c:973
    frame #98: 0x0000000103c9121a libruby.2.3.0.dylib`invoke_block_from_c_unsplattable(th=0x00007faa535450f0, block=0x00007faa54eafd80, self=140369556552120, argc=1, argv=0x0000700004004e10, blockptr=0x0000000000000000, cref=0x0000000000000000) + 90 at vm.c:998
    frame #99: 0x0000000103c7c6e4 libruby.2.3.0.dylib`vm_invoke_proc(th=0x00007faa535450f0, proc=0x00007faa54eafd80, self=140369556552120, argc=1, argv=0x0000700004004e10, blockptr=0x0000000000000000) + 244 at vm.c:1046
    frame #100: 0x0000000103c7c575 libruby.2.3.0.dylib`rb_vm_invoke_proc(th=0x00007faa535450f0, proc=0x00007faa54eafd80, argc=1, argv=0x0000700004004e10, blockptr=0x0000000000000000) + 117 at vm.c:1074
    frame #101: 0x0000000103c83589 libruby.2.3.0.dylib`vm_call_opt_call(th=0x00007faa535450f0, cfp=0x00000001063a4840, calling=0x0000700004005a40, ci=0x00007faa4dd61480, cc=0x00007faa4dd67f28) + 345 at vm_insnhelper.c:1868
    frame #102: 0x0000000103c6c850 libruby.2.3.0.dylib`vm_exec_core(th=0x00007faa535450f0, initial=0) + 12688 at insns.def:994
    frame #103: 0x0000000103c7d6c7 libruby.2.3.0.dylib`vm_exec(th=0x00007faa535450f0) + 183 at vm.c:1693
    frame #104: 0x0000000103c8f3fa libruby.2.3.0.dylib`invoke_block(th=0x00007faa535450f0, iseq=0x00007faa4ba0d9d8, self=140369556548120, block=0x00007faa550cd040, cref=0x0000000000000000, type=33, opt_pc=0) + 202 at vm.c:921
    frame #105: 0x0000000103c8f25c libruby.2.3.0.dylib`invoke_block_from_c_0(th=0x00007faa535450f0, block=0x00007faa550cd040, self=140369556548120, argc=0, argv=0x00007000040065b0, blockptr=0x0000000000000000, cref=0x0000000000000000, splattable=0) + 1148 at vm.c:973
    frame #106: 0x0000000103c9121a libruby.2.3.0.dylib`invoke_block_from_c_unsplattable(th=0x00007faa535450f0,
```

I'm wondering how I can debug this output, so I can find the reason why i have the malloc_error_break. I already checked some addresses trough "x address" but i only see some ascii output.

I did not update my gems and neither install new ones. We have changed a lot of code but we can't find when this errors pops up for the first time.

We are using ruby '2.3.7' and Puma 3.12.0 on rails 5.0.0

Comment: Seems like this could be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14045208/how-to-set-a-breakpoint-in-malloc-error-break-to-debug

Comment: @Casper i don't use xcode. I think the error is from Ruby.

Comment: Would not it be easier to migrate to Ruby 2.4?

Comment: that is not possible with my current gems.