# malloc: Heap corruption detected, free list is damaged

Tags: swift, crash, malloc, ios13, heap-corruption

My app is running fine till iOS 12. After updating my iOS version to iOS 13 beta, the app is crashing in random places and with the same error. Following is the Xcode console.

```
MyApp(618,0x10cebd800) malloc: Heap corruption detected, free list is damaged at 0x28ea33ff0
*** Incorrect guard value: 5276115984
MyApp(618,0x10cebd800) malloc: *** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug
```

Any lead to debug/solve this will be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I got this when trying to scroll and reload a table.  I think this could be useful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14045208/how-to-set-a-breakpoint-in-malloc-error-break-to-debug

Comment: @ScottyBlades in my case this is not the case, event still not sure about the actual case. After adding malloc_error_breakpoint it is showing different place every time.

Comment: Yikes.  Did you do a search on "0x28ea33ff0"? I'm maybe finding small clues by doing that.

Comment: I posted on Apple's developer site to see if anything useful will come.

Comment: @ScottyBlades did they reply?

Comment: I'm sorry @Tapas Pal, I'm not seeing a reply, and I don't remember what I did to fix it :(

Comment: [This could be helpful](https://topologyeyewear.github.io/engineering-blog/2018/03/07/heap_corruption/) but it isn't a one size fits all.

Answer (score 0):

As you stated, your app crashes in *random places*, I would also add in *random times*, this might be a clear sign of a retain cycle (could be because you forgot to capture a *weak* self inside a closure) somewhere in your code that led the ***heap*** to get saturated. At this point the system will certainly decide to terminate you app process and free up memory for other tasks.

In order to see this more clearly, try to profile your app (launch it with Instruments) with the ***Leaks*** profiling template, play around with the app and try to reproduce the scenario that led to the crash until it gets stopped (terminated), at this point Instruments will provide you with more details.