# Getting the error :pointer being freed was not allocated *** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug

Tags: ios6, breakpoints, xcode4.6

I am getting the below error :

```
malloc: *** error for object 0xa68aca0: pointer being freed was not allocated
*** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug
```

I already set the `Symbolic Breakpoint` , But Nothing happen in console, Not getting any hint in console.

I am using `xcode 4.6`

Any Help Appreciated.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You might be releasing the object too many times.

Open up the debugger console by pressing Cmd+Shift+R. and then type in the following

```
break malloc_error_break
```

This will set a breakpoint at the beginning `malloc_error_break`, you can also try printing out what's the object at 0xa68aca0

`print-object 0x1068310`

Other way to do it is using [NSZombieEnabled](http://www.raywenderlich.com/2696/how-to-debug-memory-leaks-with-xcode-and-instruments-tutorial)

[Also worth reading this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/971249/how-to-find-the-cause-of-a-malloc-double-free-error)

Comment: Yes, I found in NSZonmie tool that i m retaining the object too many time, but I am using ARC enable mode so how can i release that particular object.Help me i am new to iOS developing.