# Coredata crash while fetching

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, magicalrecord

I am getting some weird coredata error in the production app and I was able to get hold of the Crash Report.

Its Crashing with the following message at times

> *** error for object 0x17e400000: Freeing unallocated pointer
>
> *** error for object 0x17fd03730: pointer being reallocated was not allocated

And here is the stack trace

```
Crashed: SQLQueue 0x13ff15250 for datastore.sqlite
SIGABRT ABORT 0x0000000183986014

0 libsystem_kernel.dylib    __pthread_kill + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib  pthread_kill + 112
2   libsystem_c.dylib   abort + 140
3   libsystem_malloc.dylib  _nano_vet_and_size_of_live + 330
4   libsystem_malloc.dylib  nano_free + 220
5   libsqlite3.dylib    sqlite3_finalize + 244
6   CoreData    -[NSSQLiteConnection _finalizeStatement] + 100
7   CoreData    -[NSSQLiteConnection releaseSQLStatement] + 52
8   CoreData    newFetchedRowsForFetchPlan_MT + 2420
9   CoreData    _executeFetchRequest + 72
10  CoreData    -[NSSQLFetchRequestContext executeRequestUsingConnection:] + 60
11  CoreData    __52-[NSSQLDefaultConnectionManager handleStoreRequest:]_block_invoke + 260
12  libdispatch.dylib   _dispatch_client_callout + 16
13  libdispatch.dylib   _dispatch_barrier_sync_f_invoke + 84
14  CoreData    -[NSSQLDefaultConnectionManager handleStoreRequest:] + 208
15  CoreData    -[NSSQLCoreDispatchManager routeStoreRequest:] + 288
16  CoreData    -[NSSQLCore dispatchRequest:withRetries:] + 200
17  CoreData    -[NSSQLCore processFetchRequest:inContext:] + 108
18  CoreData    -[NSSQLCore executeRequest:withContext:error:] + 504
19  CoreData    __65-[NSPersistentStoreCoordinator executeRequest:withContext:error:]_block_invoke + 4512
20  CoreData    -[NSPersistentStoreCoordinator _routeHeavyweightBlock:] + 276
21  CoreData    -[NSPersistentStoreCoordinator executeRequest:withContext:error:] + 408
22  CoreData    -[NSManagedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:error:] + 572
23  CoreData    -[NSManagedObjectContext(_NestedContextSupport) _parentObjectsForFetchRequest:inContext:error:] + 456
24  CoreData    __82-[NSManagedObjectContext(_NestedContextSupport) executeRequest:withContext:error:]_block_invoke + 584
25  CoreData    internalBlockToNSManagedObjectContextPerform + 92
26  libdispatch.dylib   _dispatch_client_callout + 16
27  libdispatch.dylib   _dispatch_barrier_sync_f_invoke + 84
28  CoreData    _perform + 232
29  CoreData    -[NSManagedObjectContext(_NestedContextSupport) executeRequest:withContext:error:] + 188
30 CoreData -[NSManagedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:error:] + 572
31  *MY_APP*    NSManagedObject+MagicalRecord.m line 50__67+[NSManagedObject(MagicalRecord) MR_executeFetchRequest:inContext:]_block_invoke
```

It did happen on the main thread and I am puzzled on how to debug this. Looks like a memory issue though. Also while using instruments its showing some leaks in the app when it comes across `NSPrivateQueueConcurrencyType` .

Looking for some insights on nailing it down.

App is using MagicalRecord Extensively and here is the code block in the App Which leads to above crash. Its just a normal fetch from Main Thread. Most interestingly it crash randomly, ie it doesn't always crash but at times it crashes while doing a Fetch.

> ```
> NSPredicate *filterPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"code == %@ and pid == %@", aCode,pid];
> Permission *aPermission = [Permission MR_findFirstWithPredicate:filterPredicate];
> ```

Comment: Paste some code too.

Comment: @Sj THIS MIGHT HELP-:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15253966/getting-the-error-pointer-being-freed-was-not-allocated-set-a-breakpoint-in

Comment: Would be helpful if you could share some `fetchRequest` & `object updates` related code

Comment: @Sj OR THIS(PLEASE TRANSLATE THE PAGE FOR UNDERSTANDING)-:http://www.cocoachina.com/bbs/read.php?tid=1712611

Comment: @kb920 Added the line of code which triggers this. It happens for other entities as well

Comment: @yStack Updated the question.

Answer (score 11):

Accessing (Write or *Read*) a Managed Object on any thread other than the *Managed Object Context Queue* causes undefined behaviour & leads to random *weird* crashes.
It looks like your `Managed Object Context` was created with `NSPrivateQueueConcurrencyType` & your performing `fetch` on the `Main Queue`. This is the source of the *weird* crash.
You can either initialize `MOC` with `NSMainQueueConcurrencyType` or nest all your `fetchRequests` inside `[MOC performBlock:{...}]`

Comment: Creation:- 
let moc = (UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate)?.managedObjectContext
let privateMOC = NSManagedObjectContext(concurrencyType: .privateQueueConcurrencyType) privateMOC.parent = moc
Save:-
privateMOC.perform {
            do {
                try privateMOC.save()
               moc.performAndWait {
                    do {
                        try .moc.save()
                    } catch {
                        fatalError("Failure to save context: \(error)")}}}catch{fatalError("Failure to save context: \(error)")}}
But when I fetch it crashes randomly.

Comment: var result: [Call_rate] = []
        let request: NSFetchRequest <Call_rate> = Call_rate.fetchRequest()
        do {
            result = try self.managedObjectContext.fetch(request)
        } catch {
            fatalError("Failed to fetch employees: \(error)")
        }

In this it crashses sometimes and sometimes working proper. @ystack

Comment: @ParthBarot I would not advise using `moc.performAndWait`. Use `moc.perform{...}` instead. Also, there's a Launch Argument you can set in Xcode to diagnose if accesses are done on wrong queues. Read this: https://oleb.net/blog/2014/06/core-data-concurrency-debugging/

Answer (score 3):

Core-date managedObjectContext and managedObjects are not thread-safe - neither for writing or for **reading**.  If you ever violate this rule core-date can crash **at any time** - not necessarily where/when the violation occurred.  So even if you are on the main thread and accessing a context designed for the main thread it can still crash if you did something wrong somewhere else in your app.