# Core Data crash since iOS10 " filter array using predicate "

Tags: ios, core-data, nsarray, ios10, foundation

I have a problem with the **CoreData since iOS10** and it does happen very rarely. As it not a exception try catch doesn't help too.

Any ideas what this could be or what would have caused this?

[image]

[image: Code where this occurs]

Comment: Please show some code as well

Comment: Yeah sure I'll edit and add. Thanks

Comment: If you are using multiple contexts, please check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42248955/coredata-crash-while-fetching

Comment: I saw those too. Its entirely different

Comment: Its working for ios9 and previous versions?

Comment: Yeas. It started only since iOS10 release. XCode Organiser Crashes correctly says its happening after iOS10.

Comment: In my opinion, the problem is originating from this method `getContactsArrayFromBackground`. I think one thing you can try (just to be sure) , make a temporary array of say 5 contacts objects and apply the same predicate on that array and see if it works for iOS 10?

Comment: Yeas I'll try out thanks but these crash happens like 250 in 175000. Stats from XCode.