# Why is my crashing and saying EXC-BAD_ACCESS while trying to show a GKPeerPickerController(ARC is on)

Tags: ios, memory-management, automatic-ref-counting, exc-bad-access, gkpeerpickercontroller

Recently I have come across a problem in an app that I am developing. The app is crashing with EXC_BAD_ACCESS.  This doesn't make sense because auto-reference-counting is turned on.

In the app, I have a button that is linked to an IBAction that displays a GKPeerPickerController.

```
-(IBAction)showPicker:(id)sender
{
picker = [[GKPeerPickerController alloc ] init];
picker.delegate = self;
picker.connectionTypesMask = GKPeerPickerConnectionTypeNearby;

[picker show];
}
```

This doesn't make sense because if I try to manage the memory with calls such as release, it will give me an error saying that ARC disables that call.  So as far as I know there is nothing I can do about it.  When it crashes, the EXC_BAD_ACCESS is on the line that allocates and initializes the GKPeerPickerController.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this only happen the second time you try to launch the GKPeerPicker?

`EXC_BAD_ACCESS` is thrown when your app tries to access a memory location which it doesn't 'own'.  This can happen in numerous different ways, even with ARC, which makes it a hard crash to diagnose.

Check out this question for e.g. [EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV) crash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1733317/exc-bad-access-sigsegv-crash) - using NSZombies could be a way to track what's going on.

However, a little more understanding of what's going on might help you to understand this crash and fix it.

The first question is - how is it possible to get EXC_BAD_ACCESS when we're merely assigning a newly allocated object?  Well - the 'magic of ARC' is coming in to play here...  That simple assignment statement is assigning a new object to an instance variable.  The compiler will see that and say - Ah... that ivar might already have an object assigned to it, in which case I'd better release it...  So it will add some code for you to check for `nil` and release the ivar, before it assigns the new value.

So - I find it unlikely that the alloc/init is causing your problem, and more likely that it's whatever is currently stored in your `picker` ivar...  What happens if you make `picker` a local variable instead of an ivar?

```
-(IBAction)showPicker:(id)sender
{
     GKPeerPickerController *localPicker = [[GKPeerPickerController alloc ] init];
     localPicker.delegate = self;
     localPicker.connectionTypesMask = GKPeerPickerConnectionTypeNearby;

     [localPicker show];
}
```

Comment: Thanks I'll try making it local and see what happens.