# xcode: sigsegv crash with AddressBookUI

Tags: iphone, ios, segmentation-fault, unhandled-exception, addressbookui

I have an `error exc_bad_access (sigsegv)` but I cannot understand why. The crashlog is not very informative. Can somebody help me?

It seems to me that the error occurs when the app starts and loads the `AddressBookUI` component in order to show the contact list.

Here's the beginning of the crashlog file:

```
    Incident Identifier: 6C2731B3-027E-4058-8E93-C6471BC30B6C
CrashReporter Key:   [TODO]
Hardware Model:      iPhone5,2
Process:         Rubrica4146 [1532]
Path:            /var/mobile/Applications/1ECD07F4-123D-4720-8AB8-53ACDCD71450/Rubrica4146.app/Rubrica4146
Identifier:      com.7shapes.rubrica4146
Version:         21
Code Type:       ARM
Parent Process:  launchd [1]

Date/Time:       2013-02-15 00:01:49 +0000
OS Version:      iPhone OS 6.1 (10B143)
Report Version:  104

Exception Type:  SIGSEGV
Exception Codes: SEGV_ACCERR at 0x90000008
Crashed Thread:  0

Thread 0 Crashed:
0   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x392e95d0 _objc_msgSend + 16
1   CoreFoundation                      0x3154773f <redacted> + 271
2   CoreFoundation                      0x31547e09 <redacted> + 45
3   UIKit                               0x334750ab <redacted> + 51
4   UIKit                               0x33474fe3 <redacted> + 91
5   UIKit                               0x33474f39 <redacted> + 97
6   UIKit                               0x334f905b <redacted> + 2483
7   UIKit                               0x33569573 <redacted> + 1719
8   UIKit                               0x334b57e1 <redacted> + 913
9   AddressBookUI                       0x30dfc19d <redacted> + 241
10  AddressBookUI                       0x30dfc08d <redacted> + 65
11  CoreFoundation                      0x3154e349 __CFXNotificationPost + 1421
12  Foundation                          0x31e65b7f <redacted> + 71
13  UIKit                               0x334970df <redacted> + 735
14  UIKit                               0x3340d2d1 <redacted> + 2469
15  UIKit                               0x3340c7ad <redacted> + 73
16  UIKit                               0x3340c1ef <redacted> + 6199
17  GraphicsServices                    0x351235f7 <redacted> + 591
18  GraphicsServices                    0x35123227 <redacted> + 35
19  CoreFoundation                      0x315d23e7 <redacted> + 35
20  CoreFoundation                      0x315d238b <redacted> + 139
21  CoreFoundation                      0x315d120f <redacted> + 1383
22  CoreFoundation                      0x3154423d _CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 357
23  CoreFoundation                      0x315440c9 _CFRunLoopRunInMode + 105
24  GraphicsServices                    0x3512233b _GSEventRunModal + 75
25  UIKit                               0x334602b9 _UIApplicationMain + 1121
26  Rubrica4146                         0x0002988b main (main.m:16)
```

How can I understand why the app is crashing? What does this crash log tell me?

Comment: Please symbolicate that stacktrace, so it can be understood; numbers are meaningless.

Comment: Is there an error message describing the crash?

Comment: i will send a symbolicated crashlog as soon as possible. There's no error message for the crash. I noticed it happens only on iOS6+

Comment: These two threads may be useful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1733317/exc-bad-access-sigsegv-crash and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/327082/exc-bad-access-signal-received (particularly the 2nd answer) - NSZombie should tell you which object the error is with - exc_bad_access is an error in memory management (often trying to access released objects).

Comment: In my opinion it could happen after the app is resumed from background. But i cannot understand why...

Comment: i've added the symbolicated crash log but some lines are not symbolicated.