# Objective-C weak reference zombie

Tags: ios, objective-c, automatic-ref-counting, weak-references, nszombie

I'm trying to create a zombie object to detect sending messages to a deallocated object.

Say i have a strong property object A with a weak reference to object B. When B is deallocated my weak reference becomes nil but calling a method e.g [obj1.obj2 somemethod] simply returns nil not causing a crash.

Is there a way to test zombies using weak references? I can only crash using unsafe_unretained.

Comment: What do you want to test exactly? If you want to make a class instance a zombie just create a strong property in the class and assign self to it. If you want to detect if you are sending messages to a released weak reference or not just test for nil.

Comment: Why not just turn on NSZombie? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/535060/how-to-add-nsdebug-h-and-use-nszombie-in-iphone-sdk

Comment: I want to create a case that will crash because of a dangling pointer so i can catch it in Zombies Instrument. But sending a message to deallocated object with weak reference does not crash.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a way to test zombies using weak references

(I take it that by "zombies" you actually mean dangling pointers...)

Not directly, no. The whole *point* of ARC-weak references is that they *prevent* dangling pointers. (As you rightly say, they safely replace the potential dangling pointer with nil — and there's no penalty for sending a message to nil.)

The reason there can be dangling pointer crashes in real life is that most of Cocoa does *not* use ARC. (As you rightly say, it uses `unsafe_unretained`.)

Comment: If the question is: "How is NSZombie implemented?" this article tells you: https://mikeash.com/pyblog/friday-qa-2011-05-20-the-inner-life-of-zombies.html